# WPF Data binding alternate datacontext inside Itemscontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

What I'm trying to do is bind the controls generated by a ItemsControl.ItemTemplate to a new instance of my ContactInterface class that is created whenever I run my query function.

ContactInterface.cs:

```
class ContactInterface : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Type { get; set; }

    private string firstname;
    public string FirstName { 
        get{return this.firstname;}
        set {
            if (this.firstname != value) {
                this.firstname = value;
                this.NotifyPropertyChanged("FirstName");
            }
        }
    }
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        public void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
}
```

SQL.cs

```
partial class MainWindow
{
    private void selectContact(int? contactID)
    {
        using (ContactsDataContext context = new ContactsDataContext("Data Source=ds;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=True"))
        {
            Contact contact = context.Contacts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ContactID == contactID);
            Contact spouse = context.Contacts.SingleOrDefault(x => x.ContactID == contact.Spouse);
            Property property = context.Properties.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PropertyID == contact.Address);

            ContactInterface selectedContact= new ContactInterface();

            selectedContact.FirstName = contact.FirstName;

            profileGrid.DataContext = selectedContact;
        }

    }
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="300" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ItemsControl Name="Profile_Page_Controls">
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Grid Margin="15">
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="43" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="43" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="43" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="43" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="43" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="43" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="43" />
                                <RowDefinition Height="43" />

                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            </Grid>
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding TextContent}"/>
                                <TextBox Height="23" Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged }"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                    <Style>
                        <Setter Property="Grid.Column" Value="{Binding profile_Column}" />
                        <Setter Property ="Grid.Row" Value="{Binding profile_Row}" />
                        <Setter Property="Grid.ColumnSpan" Value="{Binding profile_Colspan}" />
                    </Style>
                </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
            </ItemsControl>
                <CheckBox Name="profile_SpouseCheck" Grid.Column="1" Margin="0,0,0,0" Checked="profile_SpouseCheck_Checked_1" Unchecked="profile_SpouseCheck_Checked_1"> Spouse</CheckBox>


            </Grid>
```

My plan is to make a new ContactInterface instance every time a user runs the selectContact() function. That new instance will be bound to the generated controls, so when the user makes and saves a change, the textboxes will update that ContactInterface instance and my other functions can grab the data from that ContactInterface to make changes to the database.

Any ideas?

Comment: This probably should belong on codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I wasn't even aware codereview.stackexchange.com existed. I'll repost there, thanks.